# WAS Server - Event Viewer error and IIS Log Error

Tags: iis, rsa, .net-framework-version, was, machinekey

I am trying to start WAS service and I got this error from Event Viewer.

`Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) is stopping because it encountered an error. The data field contains the error number.`

So then I checked the error from iis.log file

```
[04/21/2020 11:31:00] [ ***** IIS 10.0 Component Based Setup ***** ]
[04/21/2020 11:31:00] .\inetsrv\iissetup.exe  /keygen 
[04/21/2020 11:31:00] Created NetFrameworkConfigurationKey key containter
[04/21/2020 11:31:00] Created NetFrameworkConfigurationKey user key
[04/21/2020 11:31:00] Set ACLs on NetFrameworkConfigurationKey
[04/21/2020 11:31:00] Failed to create iisCngConfigurationKey key container (result=0x80090009)
[04/21/2020 11:31:00] < !!FAIL!! > Failed to create the iisCngConfigurationKey key container (result=0x80090009)
[04/21/2020 11:31:00] < !!FAIL!! > Generating IIS CNG Configuration Key Container (result=0x80090009)
[04/21/2020 11:31:00] < !!FAIL!! > Key Generation result=0x80090009
[04/21/2020 11:31:00] [ End of IIS 10.0 Component Based Setup ]
```

I went to to my RSA machine keys folder: C:\Users\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys

I understand I am supposed to back up and delete the three old RSA machine keys (1) `NetFrameworkConfigurationKey` (2) `iisWasKey` (3) `iisConfigurationKey`, however I only can find `NetFrameworkConfigurationKey` in my RSA folder that I backed up and deleted the file.

This is why you can see in iis.log error that it already created `NetFrameworkConfigurationKey` but **not** `iisWasKey` **nor** `iisConfigurationKey`

What I am looking in my RSA folder only contains two files which are NetFrameworkConfigurationKey (d6d986f09a1ee04e24c949879fdb506c_) **and** another file that I do not know what it is (5402d5bd55de56397226e45a085a4bbc_)

I could not find iisWasKey file contains (76944fb33636aeddb9590521c2e8815a_) and iisConfigureationKey file contains (6de9cb26d2b98c01ec4e9e8b34824aa2_) in my RSA folder.

Are they somewhere else or am I supposed to import the rest of keys?

Thanks

Comment: try to use the Procmon to capture the trace and see if there is any access denied issue. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)

Answer (score 0):

Try Following Commands

```
reg delete HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WAS\Parameters /v GenerateKeys /f
net start w3svc
```

This allowed the keys to be regenerated and the IIS AppPools could then be started.

Source: [https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/103c6224-52ee-41de-aa77-1a7e437e55ce/iis-on-win10-dp-wont-start-after-1903-feature-update#:~:text=%22Failed%20to%20create%20iisCngConfigurationKey%20key%20container%22%20%22Failed%20to,need%20to%20delete%2C%20such%20as%20the%20following%20one.#:~:text=%22Failed%20to%20create%20iisCngConfigurationKey%20key%20container%22%20%22Failed%20to,need%20to%20delete%2C%20such%20as%20the%20following%20one](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/103c6224-52ee-41de-aa77-1a7e437e55ce/iis-on-win10-dp-wont-start-after-1903-feature-update#:%7E:text=%22Failed%20to%20create%20iisCngConfigurationKey%20key%20container%22%20%22Failed%20to,need%20to%20delete%2C%20such%20as%20the%20following%20one.#:%7E:text=%22Failed%20to%20create%20iisCngConfigurationKey%20key%20container%22%20%22Failed%20to,need%20to%20delete%2C%20such%20as%20the%20following%20one).